# Excel VBA Cell Values showing up as intergers

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, logic

I'm working on a program with Excel's VBA functionality, but ran into a very strange logic error.

```
For SheetIndex = 1 To 6
    With ActiveSheet
    For ColIndex = 2 To 6
        For DateIndex = 0 To MinLimit

        datethingy = .Cells(1, ColIndex).Value

        If (.Cells(1, ColIndex).Value = Date_Array(DateIndex, 1)) Then

            For RowIndex = 2 To 11

'           Compare every time slot value here to every time slot value in the array
            datethingy = Trim(CStr(.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value)) 'ERROR OCCURS HERE

            If (Trim(CStr(.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value)) = Date_Array(DateIndex, 2)) Then
                .Cells(RowIndex, ColIndex).Value = "Checked"
            End If

            Next
        End If
        Next
    Next
    End With

    SheetIndex = SheetIndex + 1
    Application.Worksheets(SheetIndex).Activate
Next
```

So in the code above, I go through a series of cell values and make comparisons to values I already have in my array. However, when I draw the values from the cells, rather than "8:30", it comes up as "0.354166666...7". I have no idea why it's coming up like this, I'm even making sure it's being compared as a string and not as an int or anything else.

Here is where I set the values for the sheet's cells.

```
.Cells(2, 1).Value = "8:30"
.Cells(3, 1).Value = "9:00"
.Cells(4, 1).Value = "10:15"
.Cells(5, 1).Value = "11:30"
.Cells(6, 1).Value = "12:30"
.Cells(7, 1).Value = "13:30"
.Cells(8, 1).Value = "14:45"
.Cells(9, 1).Value = "16:00"
.Cells(10, 1).Value = "17:15"
.Cells(11, 1).Value = "18:15"

With Range("A2", "A11")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
    .ColumnWidth = 15
End With

ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.AutoFit
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Check the format of the cell, while the input is "date/time", the cell's format could be "number" and turn your time into numeric presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores times and dates as numbers.  Each whole number is a day and hours, minutes and seconds are broken down as fractions of that day. 8:30 is just a time so there is no whole number and 8.5/24 = 0.3541667.

You can test this with this code and this may provide you a way to format your inputs.  Type 8:30 into cell A1

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "8:30" 'returns false
    Debug.Print Format(sheet1.Range("A1").Value, "h:mm") = "8:30" 'returns true
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A1").Text = "8:30" 'return true
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right! So then, would I be able to convert this into a string? Or would I have to convert the string into a date to do the comparison?

Comment: The format function will return a string.  I don't know exactly what you're comparing to so that would determine if you need to make a conversion.  I thought of another way to get the data from your sheet and edited that into the answer.  I think it makes things a little simpler.

Comment: To be honest, if I had known there was a .Text property, that would have been the first thing I tried. everything is in working order now, thanks!